# Recoger datos de xml online

Tags: java, xml, api, jsp

Os explico un poco lo que quiero hacer y lo que he probado. Estoy haciendo un proyecto en java con JSP de una pagina de apuestas. Entonces, tengo una api de resultados-futbol.com que me da todos los partidos de fútbol. Este el el formato del xml. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces mi idea es recoger los datos, y meterlos en una Base de datos. He probado cosas, pero todo era con xml en el propio ordenador. No he conseguido sacar nada con xml remoto. ¿Alguna idea o algún trozo de código para hacerme una idea?

```
package cargarXml;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;    
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.jdom2.Document;         // |
import org.jdom2.Element;          // |\ Librerías
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;    // |/ JDOM
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder; // |
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;



/**
 *
 * @author imanol
 */
public class CargarXml {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException,                 ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
        //Se crea un SAXBuilder para poder parsear el archivo
//    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
//    File xmlFile = new File( "http://apiclient.resultados-    futbol.com/scripts/api/api.php?    key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&tz=Europe/Madrid&format=xml&req=matchs&league=1&    round=38&order=twin&twolegged=1&year=2017" );
URL url = new URL("http://apiclient.resultados-futbol.com/scripts/api/api.php?



     key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&tz=Europe/Madrid&format=xml&req=matchs&league=1&
round=38&order=twin&twolegged=1&year=2017");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());




try
{
    //Se crea el documento a traves del archivo
    //Document document = (Document) builder.build( xmlFile );

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = (Document) dBuilder.parse( in );

    //Se obtiene la raiz 'tables'
    Element rootNode = doc.getRootElement();

    //Se obtiene la lista de hijos de la raiz 'tables'
    List list = rootNode.getChildren( "matchs" );

    //Se recorre la lista de hijos de 'tables'
    for ( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ )
    {
        //Se obtiene el elemento 'tabla'
        Element tabla = (Element) list.get(i);

        //Se obtiene el atributo 'nombre' que esta en el tag 'tabla'
        //String nombreTabla = tabla.getAttributeValue("nombre");

        System.out.println( "Tabla: " );

        //Se obtiene la lista de hijos del tag 'tabla'
        List lista_campos = tabla.getChildren();

        System.out.println( "\tNombre\t\tTipo\t\tValor" );

        //Se recorre la lista de campos
        for ( int j = 0; j < lista_campos.size(); j++ )
        {
            //Se obtiene el elemento 'campo'
            Element campo = (Element)lista_campos.get( j );

            //Se obtienen los valores que estan entre los tags '<campo></campo>'
            //Se obtiene el valor que esta entre los tags '<nombre></nombre>'
            String nombre = campo.getChildTextTrim("id");

            //Se obtiene el valor que esta entre los tags '<tipo></tipo>'
            String tipo = campo.getChildTextTrim("year");

            //Se obtiene el valor que esta entre los tags '<valor></valor>'
            String valor = campo.getChildTextTrim("group");

            System.out.println( "\t"+nombre+"\t\t"+tipo+"\t\t"+valor);
        }
    }
}catch ( IOException io ) {
    System.out.println( io.getMessage() );
}
}

}
```

Código que he probado, y el error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl cannot be
>   cast to org.jdom2.Document    at
>   cargarXml.CargarXml.main(CargarXml.java:49)
>   C:\Users\imanol.OFICINA\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Estoy bastante interesado en que encuentran la solución a este problema, estoy en una situación similar.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con _No he conseguido sacar nada con xml remoto_? Puedes poner algo de código para ver cuál es el problema que tienes.

Comment: ya esta el codigo que he probado..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que has importado la librería incorrecta. En lugar de:

```
import org.jdom2.Document;         // |
import org.jdom2.Element;          // |\ Librerías
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;    // |/ JDOM
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
```

deberías de usar:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
```

Y para leer el documento:

```
URL url = new URL("http://apiclient.resultados-futbol.com/scripts   /api/api.php?
 key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&tz=Europe/Madrid&format=xml&req=matchs&league=1&round=38&order=twin&twolegged=1&year=2017");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = (Document) db.parse(in);  
System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("match");
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());

    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

        System.out.println("Team1 : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("team1").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Team2 : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("team2").item(0).getTextContent());


    }
}
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Me da un error en Element rootNode = doc.getRootElement();

Comment: cannot find symbol

Comment: Al poner eso sin quitar  Element rootNode = doc.getRootElement() me sigue el fallo en el mismo lado, y si lo quito me dan mas fallos debajo, porque no esta declarado rootNode

Comment: Creo que estás mezclando las 2 librerías. Revisa los imports que tienes. Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: Cierto, estaba mezclado otra libreria, pero ya lo tengo modificado y me sigue el fallo en el mismo sitio :S

Comment: ¿A qué error te refieres, al ClassCastException?

Comment: Pues que ahora me dan fallo todo los getchildren,

Comment: Puedes ser más específico en tus respuestas. "me dan fallo" no aporta ninguna información. De todas formas si el error no tiene nada que ver con esta pregunta deberías de aceptar esta respuesta si te ha ayudado y abrir una nueva pregunta. Y si está relacionado aporta más datos para poder ayudarte. Fijate que en mi respuesta no se usa getChildren para obtener un elemento. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no habia visto el ultimo edit de la respuesta, Gracias brother, me has ayudado mucho +1